# Area of parametric surface (theory)

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, parametric, surface-integrals

In the picture below $\left \|\Delta u_i r_u \times  \Delta v_i r_v \right \|$ is the area of the parallelogram $\Delta T_i$
Can someone please explain why the sides of the parallelogram $\Delta T_i$ are $\Delta u_i r_u$ and 
$\Delta v_i r_v$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They aren't. Moreover, $\Delta T_i$ need not be a parallelogram at all, nor should be expect it to be any sort of planar region.

The region $\Delta T_i$ is approximated by the parallelogram you describe. The idea here is that as we let $\Delta u_i, \Delta v_j$ go to zero, the difference between the area of this parallelogram and the area of $\Delta T_i$ becomes negligible.

Comment: If you read what's written in the picture "...construct a tangent plane" $T_i$.If it is a plane, therefore is a planar region. On the other hand, it is the other way around, the incrementals of the surface $\Delta S_i$ over  the surface $\Delta D_i$ are aproximated by the surface $\Delta T_i$(tangent plane). And as it says in the picture, the sides are the above indicated.

Comment: Then the author says that $\Delta T_i$ is the region of the surface corresponding to the rectangle $D_i$ in the domain of the parametrization and says this is approximated by a rectangle $\Delta S_i$ in the tangent plane. The author is just using terrible notation. 

I think I understand your question, though. Think about how we construct tangent planes using parametrizations in analogy with the 1 dimensional case where one easy to obtain tangent vector is the derivative of the parametrization.